# Error in displaying data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am trying to display data in the view for a member's profile. When I run the inspect option on the variable, it prints out all of the data on the profile variable. But, when I have it only call a column, I get an error.

I run the same code on a different variable and it prints out; so, I am a bit confused on what is going on. Is it because the Active Record has a relation? Here is the code:

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @show_page = params[:id]
  @member = current_member
  @profile = Profile.where(member_id: current_member.id)    
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<hr>
<%= @show_page.inspect %>
<hr>
<%= @profile.inspect %>
<hr>
<%= @member.inspect %>
<hr>

<p>
  <strong>Member ID:</strong>
  <%= @member.id %>
</p>
```

**View in Browser**

```
"8"
```

---

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 6, f_name: "Test", l_name: "Member", u_name: "testing", security: "10", private: "1", avatar: nil, birthday: nil, phone: nil, address1: nil, address2: nil, city: nil, state: nil, zip: nil, long: nil, lat: nil, facebook: nil, twitter: nil, instagram: nil, pinterest: nil, googleplus: nil, motto: nil, created_at: "2017-12-23 05:15:53", updated_at: "2017-12-23 05:15:53", member_id: 8>]>
```

---

```
#<Member id: 8, email: "testing@t.com", created_at: "2017-12-19 20:02:34", updated_at: "2017-12-23 05:15:37">
```

---

```
Member ID: 8
```

Now, when I add the following code into the show page, I get an error.

**show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>User Name:</strong>
  <%= @profile.u_name %>
</p>
```

**ERROR**

```
Showing /Users/topher/Dropbox/railsapps/~sandboxes/temporary/app/views/profiles/show.html.erb where line #21 raised:

undefined method `u_name' for #<Profile::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fcb2583b920>
Did you mean?  name
```

I am just confused on if there is a different way that I need to be calling the data found in the variable. The only difference between the `@member` and `@profile` print outs that I can see is the `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [` prefixed to `@profile`. Does this mean that I need to call the information differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#where` is query method, and returns records matching query conditions wrapped in `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. Which explains why you are getting this error. To resolve it, you need to change it to:

```
@profile = Profile.where(member_id: current_member.id).first
```

Which will return first record matching given member id to `@profile` instead of `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

However, you must use a finder method in case you want to find a particular record. So better and cleaner approach would be:

```
@profile = Profile.find_by(member_id: current_member.id)
```

Comment: Thank you Parth, this and the answer by @Junan both helped me with my error! I marked yours as the answer, as it explains the reason for the error and the solution well. Changing to `find_by` removes the error and shows the data.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line in `profiles_controller.rb` like

`@profile = Profile.find_by(member_id: current_member.id)`

As you are using `where` clause on `Profile` it will return an array of `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects. But you need a single `@profile` object not `@profiles` object. Thats you should use `find_by` method instead of `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you Junan, this and the answer by @Parth both helped me with my error!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your line on the show method

```
@show_page = params[:id]
```

You need to indicate model where to contain the params id

```
@show_page = Model.find(params[:id]) #=> model is your model which you can using
```

I think will help